# Calculating median with a GROUP BY in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I'm running MariaDB 10.3 which supports the [`MEDIAN` function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/median/), and in simple cases this function seems to work well.  However I'm having trouble making it work in complex situations.  Currently I'm trying to calculate the number, mean and median value for each of several types of item.  Here's a MWE:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (type INTEGER, value INTEGER);
INSERT INTO items (type, value) VALUES (1,1), (1,3), (1,4), (2,10), (2,32), (2,42);
SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS count, AVG(value) AS mean, 
  MEDIAN(value) OVER(PARTITION BY type) AS median FROM items GROUP BY type;
DROP TABLE items;
```

This calculates the count and mean correctly, but not the median:

| type | count | mean | median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2.6667 | 1.0000000000 |
| 2 | 3 | 28.0000 | 10.0000000000 |

I expect it's some silly error in my SQL, but I can't for the life of me see it, and no errors or warnings are reported.  I've tried dropping the `PARTITION BY type` which changes the medians returned but they're still not correct.  Removing the `OVER` clause results in a syntax error.

I don't understand why this isn't working.  If I just do the following, the median is calculated correctly, though with lots of duplicate lines, but adding `GROUP BY type` gives the erroneous values above.

```sql
SELECT type, MEDIAN(value) OVER(PARTITION BY type) AS median FROM items;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT type, 
       COUNT(*) AS count, 
       AVG(value) AS mean 
FROM items 
GROUP BY type;
```

is an aggregation query and if you add to it the window function `MEDIAN()` it will be calculated on the results that it returns which are:

| type | count | mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2.6667 |
| 2 | 3 | 28.0000 |

with an arbitrary value for `value` (which seems to be the first of each partition).

What you should do is get the median in a subquery and then aggregate:

```
SELECT type, 
       COUNT(*) AS count, 
       AVG(value) AS mean,
       median
FROM (       
  SELECT *, MEDIAN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY type) AS median 
  FROM items
) t
GROUP BY type, median;
```

Or, use only window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY type) AS count, 
       AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY type) AS mean,
       MEDIAN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY type) AS median
FROM items;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=82137679b6dd59c1f2a7fa855cbfcc2a).